# Hide Monitor form Host OS

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, multiple-monitors

I have Ubuntu 13.10 running as a guest OS in VirtualBox on Windows 8. I have two monitors set up on Windows, and I know I can run Ubuntu in full screen mode, but that still allows windows to be hidden behind the guest OS.  Is there a way to make VirtualBox "take over" the second monitor so the Windows OS only sees one and Linux sees one?